# Why can't I make lang an element?

Tags: html, lang

I recently came across this tidbit of code below while debugging a website of mine.

```html
<lang="[insert language code here]">
```

Why should we never ever do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because lang is an attribute, not a tag and it is defined inside HTML tag

```
<html lang="en">
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I have been trying to explain this to someone.

Comment: You can accept the answer to help future seekers. Happy to help you